# When does classLoader load imports?

Tags: java, classloader

Assume, that I have class with static methods only. Will class loader load every imported class when loading class to memory? Or it will only load imports when a method from this would need access to it?

Question is whether class loader loads imports when the class is loaded to memory, or just before some methods want to use them.
If it is the first option I would probably need to divide some of my *Util* classes, to be more *specialized*.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you can test it as follows:

```
package pkg1;

public class Test {

    static {
        System.out.println("Hello 111");
    }

    public static void meth() {
        System.out.println("Hello 222");
    }
}
```

Test 1:

```
package pkg2;

import pkg1.Test;

public class Tester {    

    public static void main(String... args) {                   
        Test t;       
    }    
}
```

That prints nothing.

Test 2:

```
package pkg2;

import pkg1.Test;

public class Tester {    

    public static void main(String... args) {                   
        Test.meth();        
    }

}
```

Prints:

```
Hello 111
Hello 222
```

So, just because you have imported a class does not mean the classloader will load the class into the memory. It loads it dynamically when it's used.

Comment: Class could still be `loaded`, this code shows the class is not `initialized` until it is used. Only way I know to test loading is to run `java -verbose:class <your_flags>`. This will cause the JVM to print when a class is loaded.

Answer (score 5):

I don't claim to know a lot about the class loader, but if you're talking about import statements then the class loader is irrelevant.

Import statements exist purely to allow the developer to use short class names rather than the fully qualified name of each class referenced in the class being written. The compiler uses those import statements very early on to resolve the names of the referenced classes before a single line of bytecode is created.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the static code block at the top of a class file with a report (i.e. a print statement ) will give you a good idea of when the loading happens in your particular application.

However, when dealing with corner cases, like dynamic classes,  inner static classes, or classes off the classpath that are dynamically loaded, you will have to be careful - because these classes might actually be loaded MULTIPLE times in an application.

Comment: [citation needed] for the "multiple times" part.